# Accessing sub-sub site list using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have a ctx object which points to the root site collection e.g "`https://rootsitecoll`" we are doing some processing on the list on the root level. Then we have a list at the sub sub site level "`https://rootsitecoll/subsite1/subsite2/List1`". Can we use the same

```
 using (var ctx = new ClientContext(rootSiteCollectionURL))
    {
//can i use the same ctx to accesss the list under the sub sub site level, if so how
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use the same context. To access the list in the subsite, you need to use the `site.OpenWeb` method.

You can use it as below:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(rootSiteCollectionURL))
{

    Web oWeb = context.Site.OpenWeb("server-relativeurl"); 
    //Web oWeb = context.Site.OpenWeb("subsite1/subsite2/");
    context.Load(oWeb);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    var list = oWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("List1");
    context.Load(list);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    ...your code to process the list items
}
```

Comment: hi @spStacker, did you try the above code ? Is it working for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same context and read all the subsites. You can refer the following code.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Username, Password);

var subWebs = ctx.Web.Webs;
ctx.Load(subWebs);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach(var subWeb in subWebs)
{

    ctx.Load(subWeb);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.Write(subWeb.Title);
}
```